# How do I remove login with Samba?

Tags: server, samba

Hey I set up a home server using Ubuntu Server 11.04 and I want to let all the computers in my house access the server through Windows Explorer and Finder. But once its detected it asks for the Username and password of the root user. Is there a way I can just let anyone access it without a password. If not, can I then create a user for each person to have there own special server storage? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can set line the `guest ok = yes` for your printers and devices in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to let non-authenticated users access it. If your samba server is behind a firewall, that should be safe enough.

However, adding users to your samba server is done via the `smbpasswd` command, use `sudo smbpasswd -a <username>` to create their samba-login.